# Re adding myself to a Group

Tags: facebook-groups

I was added to a group but a few months later removed myself from the group via my phone. Punching too many "yes" answers I hit the button that said "prevent anyone from adding you to this group again". So now I want to be in that group again and I don't know how....

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation once. The way I solved this problem was by asking the group admin to copy and send me the full URL that appears when s/he opens the facebook group page (excluding strings like &view=doc if any). Example: `https://www.facebook.com/groups/298596911542862/` After I got the URL and pasted it in my browser, an "Ask to join" button appeared which let me request the group admin to add me in the group. After the admin accepted, I was back in again. I hope this solves your problem.